# Why the self-information is $-\log(p(m))$?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, entropy, probability, information

Why is [self-information](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-information) given by $-\log(p(m))$?

> Shannon derived a measure of information content called the self-information or "surprisal" of a message $m$:
>
> $$I(m)  = \log \left( \frac{1}{p(m)} \right)  =  - \log( p(m) ) \, $$
> where $p(m)$  is the probability that message $m$ is chosen from all possible choices in the message space

If $p=1$ there is no information in the message?

Comment: Yes, events that always occur do not communicate information.

Comment: It is because there is already a "memory" about this event?

Comment: Assume you have a detector that measures whether energy is conserved, and only that.  I'm trying to send you a signal.  I manipulate your environment in an arbitary way, and you use your detector to run experiments on stuff around you.  You'll never tell that I'm trying to send you a signal, no matter what, because all your dtector will ever do is say "yep, energy is conserved".

Comment: @messias: I'd say it's not so much the memory as the knowledge that it will always be event $m$. For example, suppose I always send you the letter `b`, the entropy for the next bit is 0 because you know that it's going to be `b`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several possible answers to this. One is to look at Shannon's definition of the entropy,
$$
H = -\sum_i p_i \log p_i,
$$
and note that it has the form of an expectation: $H$ is the expected value of $-\log p_i$, so it makes sense to give a name to that latter quantity. This is nice if you understand the value of the entropy. In Shannon's paper ('A Mathematical Theory of Communication', readily available online) he gives a very nice derivation of the definition of $H$ from first principles, and it's well worth going through that if you really want to understand where these quantities come from.

But there's also a more intuitive, heuristic way to understand the self-information. Let's take the logarithm to base 2, so that the surprisal is measured in bits.

Now, let's imagine that we have an $n$-bit communication channel, and that all possible messages are equally likely. So for $n=8$, a message might be something like $00101110$. How much information do we gain if we receive that particular message? Intuitively, it should be fairly obvious that it's 8 bits.

Now let's ask what was the probability of receiving that message? Well, that's given by $\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^8$, or 1 in 256. Given this, we can calculate the self-information as $-\log_2 \frac{1}{256} = 8$ bits.

It's easy to see that this will work with any $n$. So the self-information is the (unique) way to convert probabilities into bits so that it agrees with our intuition in such simple example cases, while also not doing anything weird in less intuitive cases.

As others pointed out in the comments, when $p=1$ there is no information in the message. This actually fits nicely with our intuition as well. For example: how much information do you gain if I tell you we are located on the planet Earth? Well, none at all, since you already knew that. In your mind there was no probability that we could be located on any other planet, and therefore my message didn't tell you anything. In general if you know something is going to happen you won't be surprised when it does, so it makes sense that the surprisal should be zero in such cases.

Answer (score 4):

For me, the thing that really gives Shannon's definition legs is [Shannon's Noiseless Coding Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shannon's_source_coding_theorem). It proves the following remarkable and important fact:

Let an information source send a message comprising *statistically independent symbols* and suppose that these symbols belong to an $N$ letter alphabet, and that the propability of transmission of the $j^{th}$ symbol be $p_j$.

Suppose now that the source sends through a communication channel that can sends 0s and 1s such that it can noiselessly send $h$ bits per second, but no faster (you might imagine a telecomunications link that can reliably switch between "off" to "on" state $h$ times per second).

Suppose now we send $M$ symbols through this link (note that there will need to be a coding scheme, such as ASCII or Unicode, to transform our symbols into sequences of 0s and 1s) at a rate of $s$ symbols per second.

Then the noiseless coding theorem shows that there exists a coding scheme such that the probability of error $\to 0$ as $M\to\infty$ if $\frac{h}{s} > H = -\sum\limits_{j=1}^Np_j\,\log\,p_j$.

Conversely, if $\frac{h}{s} < H = -\sum\limits_{j=1}^N p_j\,\log\,p_j$, then the probability of transmission error $\to 1$ as $M\to\infty$ no matter what coding scheme may be used.

In other words, if you allocate $H$ bits per symbol in your link capacity, and if you are willing to buffer up messages so that they are sent in big chunks $M$ symbols long, then you can find a coding scheme that will make the probability of transmission error arbitrarily small. *"You are bound to succeed"* by making $M$ big enough.

If you allocate $H-\epsilon$ bits per symbol, where $\epsilon>0$, then there will certainly be transmission errors no matter how small $\epsilon$ is. *"If you scrimp on the channel's maximum transmission rate, even a teeny tiny bit, you are bound to fail"*.

$H$ really is a measure of exactly how fast you have to signal, and not a jot more, in bits per symbol, if you want to transmit messages reliabily for this information source.

See also the appendix to [E. T. Jaynes, "Information Theory and Statistical Mechanics"](http://bayes.wustl.edu/etj/articles/theory.1.pdf), which shows that $H$ can also be construed as the unique function that fulfills three reasonable properties of continuity, monotonicity and the so-called "composition law".

Answer (score 0):

The other answers already do a very good job, but let me stress this point: we are assuming that the "experimenter" has a priori knowledge of the probability distribution. This should help in clarifying why the "If $p=1 $ there is no information" claim may sound wrong.

Let's suppose (as usual) that the "experimenter" knows that $p(m_X)=1$, that is the whole message space is $\{m_X\}$. It's then intuitive that the information gained from finding out that $m_{measured }= m_X$ is zero. 
For the sake of the subsequent discussion, notice that this example is equivalent to a message space $\{m_X, m_Y\}$, where $p(m_X)=1$ and $p(m_Y)=0$.

Things are different if the "experimenter" is not aware of the probability distribution in advance. In this case, an experimental finding such as $m_{measured}=\{ m_X, m_X,  m_X,  m_X,  m_X , \dots_{1000 \, times}\}$ will make the "experimenter" pretty confident that if the  message space is $\{m_X, m_Y\}$, then this is not a fair coin distribution! (of course he cannot claim this with complete certainty). In this broader sense, the "experimenter" is learning that the distribution is very similar to a $p(m_X)=1$ distribution.

Answer (score 0):

Let me point out that the Shannon entropy has an axiomatic definition which leads one to the form
$$S_n(p_1,\ldots,p_n) = - C \sum_{j} p_j \log p_j,$$
where $C$ is an undetermined constant. The axioms are

1. $S_2(p,1-p)$ is a continuous function of $p$
2. $S_n(p_1,\ldots,p_n)$ may be determined by $S_2$ by an iterative procedure using

$$S_n(p_1,\ldots,p_n) = S_{n-1}(p_1+p_2,p_3,\ldots,p_n) + (p_1 + p_2)S(\frac{p_1}{p_1+p_2},\frac{p_2}{p_1+p_2}).$$

This second axiom really explains everything, [in my view](https://arxiv.org/abs/1108.2874). It says that the Shannon entropy plays well with factorization of your data. Indeed, one can think of the left hand side as the total information gained by looking at the value of a random variable distributed according to $p_1,\ldots,p_n$. Now imagine we have two devices: device 1 which can tell apart any of the values except it cannot decide between value 1 and value 2; and device 2 which can only tell apart 1 and 2. If we combine devices 1 and 2, we should be able to gain all of the information about our random variable. The expected information gain is exactly the RHS of the above relation.